# Can't use "insert picture from sharepoint" on sharepoint 2010 blog?

Tags: sharepoint

I am the admin for a site colelction and when I create a wiki I can use "insert from sharepoint" when I add pictures but when I create a blog is greyed out. Why can I use it on the wiki but not on the blog?

I have activated publishing on both the site collection level and on the site level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These components/content types

- Enterprise Wiki
- Publishing Page

Allow "Insert from Sharepoint" because the content field is of type "Publishing HTML"

These components

- Wiki
- Blog

Don't have the "Insert from Sharepoint" action, because the content field is of type "Multiple lines of text"